# Overload constructors with normal and generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have a Response class with two constructors. One receive a Result object and other a generic Result object.

How to declare the generic constructor of Response class to get the generic object?

In this sample code, the non-generic constructor is used.

```
var result = new Result<SomeModel>();
var response = new Response(result); // should use the generic constructor but uses the normal

public interface IModel
{
}

public class SomeModel : IModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Result<T> : Result where T : class, IModel
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Response(Result<IModel> data)
    {
    }

    public Response(Result data)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this and look at the message why it won't compile: `new Response((Result<IModel>)result)` -- this is a (co|contra)variance thing. `Result<SomeModel>` isn't `Result<IModel>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Result<IModel>` isn't the same as a `Result<SomeModel>`.

You have two options: first, you can make `Response` generic as `Response<T> where T : IModel` and then change the constructor to take a `Result<T>`.

Alternately, you can define an `IResult<out T>` interface (implemented by `Result<T>` with only a getter for the model property, and change the constructor of `Response` to take an `IResult<IModel>`; this is called "covariance".